# Can a thread that is running see changes in private fields?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to implement a kind of thread pool, that when I start a Thread, my own class that extends thread, its run method will run forever or until some condition is met.

1. While the thread is running it should receive work, as Callable interface.
2. When it retrieves the value it should notify a Condition variable.

```java
private class Worker extends Thread {
    private Callable<T> toCall;
    private T result;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true) {
                if(toCall == null && /* Other condition accessing Outer class field */){
                    // Idle for too much time
                    break; // Finish thread run normally
                }

                if(toCall != null && /* Other condition accessing Outer class field */){
                    // Is this block reached when setCallable is invoked after this thread is running ? 
                    result = toCall.call();
                    hasResult.signal(); // Condition variable
                    toCall = null;
                }
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException ie){
            // TODO 
        }
    }

    public void setCallable(Callable<T> toCall){
        this.toCall = toCall;
    }

    public void getResult(){
        return result;
    }
}
```

My main doubts are:

- Does this thread see the change in `toCall` variable?
- After it uses this variable and sets it to null, can another call to `setCallable` be safe?
- Finally is this a good way of having a thread always run and give it work when needed? The thread that sends work will have to wait for the `hasResult` Condition to be signaled.

I'm trying to implement my own very simple ThreadPoolExecutor and my approach is to have a list of these Worker's, creating them upon need, and reusing those from this list that aren't doing anything.

If this approach is wrong whats the best way to achive this functionality?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I recommend to you to read more about Futures, it can help you

Comment: You are always running in a thread, the main thread is created for you but it is just a thread like any other and if you create a new thread it works the same.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this thread see the change in toCall variable ?

In terms of visibility, with no synchronization whatsoever, the answer is not necessarily.

> after it uses this variable and sets it to null, can another call to setCallable be safe ?

This is where the implementation may not be "safe". What happens if two threads submit a `Callable` at the same time to the worker? Given the above code, it will process only one of them and ignore the other. A better alternative may be to have the workers poll a shared queue of tasks. You can use something like a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to save the tasks. One of the methods there allow you to poll the queue with a timeout.

> Finally is this a good way of having a thread always run and give it work when needed?

I don't think so, for the reason mentioned above.

Comment: "why wouldn't it?" Because the variable isn't volatile, and it's not read and written in a synchronized block.

Comment: @AndyTurner You're right (I've thought about this). It's not really clear however if the OP was questioning visibility. The title talks about "private" so I thought more about accessibility. I'll try to clarify in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by [AR.3 in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41350287/3182664), the thread may not necessarily see the change in the `toCall` variable.

Declaring the variable as `volatile` is one way of making this point safe, but (without diving too deeply into the details of the Java Memory Model), this may not be necessary. More precisely: It may not be **sufficient** here, because there clearly is a race condition involving your `toCall` variable:

```
   | Worker thread:                            |  External thread:
---| ------------------------------------------|--------------------------------
0: | while(true) {                             |
1: |                                           |  worker.setCallable(c);
2: |     if(toCall != null){                   |
3: |                                           |  worker.setCallable(null);
4: |         result = toCall.call(); // CRASH! |
5: |
```

So an external thread may set the `toCall` variable to a non-`null` value. The worker thread may find that `toCall!=null`, and enter the body of the `if`-statement. At this point, an external thread may set `toCall` to `null`, causing a `NullPointerException` when the worker attempts to do `toCall.call()`.

Of course, this could be fixed by wrapping accesses to the `toCall` variable into synchronization blocks. And then, it would not have to be `volatile` any more - that's what I referred to above.

There may be some other synchronization issues with your code. You did not give us all details, particularly about the role of the `hasResult` variable. And you did not say whether there is a particular reason of why you wanted to implement this on your own.

But in general:

There are easier, more elegant and more idiomatic ways of achieving what you probably intended. One of the comments already pointed you to the [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) class, which offers the functionality that you seemingly wanted to implement there. Depending on where and how the synchronization (i.e. the *waiting*, in this case) should take place, there are different options. The easiest could be an executor service:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future<T> future = executorService.submit(toCall);

// Whereever this should be consumed:
T t = future.get(); // Will wait until the result is computed
```

Alternatively, the [`CompletableFeature`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) class offers mechanisms for adding a "callback" that will be informed when the result is avaliable.

Comment: I understood the race condition that might happen with the setCallable method, but it is intended to pass only non-null variables, so the only one who can set the toCall variable to null is the worker thread, what i'm trying to achive is maintaining a number of threads, alive, and when i need to i give them work and collect it. the role of hasResult is for signaling when the work is done and the calling thread may consume it. After it has been signaled result is obtained getResult method, and of course all of these functionalities are private, i think it may work, what is your opinion ?

Comment: @EduG 1. Whether or not the race condition is a problem may depend on the use case. Similarly, there currently is no mechanism to make sure that the `doCall` is really executed. When doing `w.setCallable(a); w.setCallable(b);`, then `a` might not be executed at all. 2. The *name* `hasResult` already suggested that, but it is not clear how exactly it is used. I assume that a thread is *waiting* for this condition. And as I said above, then this functionality is basically the same as the functionality that is offered by `ExecutorService`+`Future` (in a more robust, idiomatic form)